flutter_local_notification `ongoing` doesn't prevent the user to swipe & delete the notification
essentially I want to create a permanent notification using flutter_local_notification (I'm working on Android 14).
In the documentation, I've found the ongoing param that prevents the notification to be cleared when the "clear all" button is clicked, but in effect, the user is still able to swipe the notification deleting the notification.
How can I also prevent the user swiping and deleting the notification?
I know it is possible, for example in Google Wallet, when you add a boarding pass for a flight, it shows a fully permanent notification with a quick link to the ticket.
I would like to get a fully permanent notification in my app as well.

Here's my code:
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationProvider {
  late FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  static int taskNotificationId = 0;

  NotificationProvider() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  }

  void _onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(
      NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {
    final String? payload = notificationResponse.payload;
    if (notificationResponse.payload != null) {
      print('notification payload: $payload');
    }
  }

  void _onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
    print("id $id");
    print("title $title");
    print("body $body");
    print("payload $payload");
  }

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
            onDidReceiveLocalNotification: _onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

    final LinuxInitializationSettings initializationSettingsLinux =
        LinuxInitializationSettings(defaultActionName: 'Open notification');

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
      macOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
      linux: initializationSettingsLinux,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: _onDidReceiveNotificationResponse,
    );

    const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'todo-master-channel', // ID
      'ToDo Master', // Name
      description: 'To Do Master Task', // Description
      importance: Importance.max,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
        .requestNotificationsPermission();
  }

  Future<void> showTaskNotification({
    required String title,
    required String description,
  }) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'task-channel',
      'Task Notification',
      channelDescription: 'Notification reminder for Tasks',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ongoing: true,
      autoCancel: false,
      ticker: 'ticker',
      visibility: NotificationVisibility.public,
    );
    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      taskNotificationId,
      title,
      description,
      notificationDetails,
      payload: 'item x',
    );

    taskNotificationId++;
  }

}


Here's my attemp to create a thread and then link to it a notification. The thread is created, but the notification can be deleted by each the delete all button and the swiping gesture.
Futhermore, when I call the cleanUp() function it returns another notification with a Failure error.

import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background/flutter_background.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class NotificationProvider {
  static int taskNotificationId = 0;

  static final NotificationProvider _instance =
      NotificationProvider._internal();
  factory NotificationProvider() => _instance;
  NotificationProvider._internal();

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
    final DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsDarwin =
        DarwinInitializationSettings(
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {
        print(
            "Notification Received: [id: $id, title: $title, body: $body, payload: $payload]");
      },
    );
    final LinuxInitializationSettings initializationSettingsLinux =
        LinuxInitializationSettings(
      defaultActionName: 'Open notification',
    );
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
      macOS: initializationSettingsDarwin,
      linux: initializationSettingsLinux,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
          (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
        print('Notification payload: ${notificationResponse.payload}');
      },
    );

    Workmanager().initialize(_callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);
  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static void _callbackDispatcher() {
    Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
      await NotificationProvider()._showNotification();
      return Future.value(true);
    });
  }

  Future<void> createNotification() async {
    if (await _requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations()) {
      if (await _requestPermissions()) {
        const androidConfig = FlutterBackgroundAndroidConfig(
          notificationTitle: "Background Service",
          notificationText: "Service is running",
          notificationImportance: AndroidNotificationImportance.Max,
        );

        bool initialized =
            await FlutterBackground.initialize(androidConfig: androidConfig);
        if (initialized) {
          await FlutterBackground.enableBackgroundExecution();
          await Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
            "1",
            "simplePeriodicTask",
            frequency:
                Duration(minutes: 15), // Note: minimum 15 minutes on Android
            constraints: Constraints(
              networkType: NetworkType.connected,
              requiresBatteryNotLow: true,
              requiresCharging: false,
              requiresDeviceIdle: false,
              requiresStorageNotLow: false,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'task-channel',
      'Task Notification',
      channelDescription: 'Permanent Task Notification reminder',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      ongoing: true,
      autoCancel: false,
    );
    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );
    const LinuxNotificationDetails linuxPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        LinuxNotificationDetails(
      defaultActionName: 'Open notification',
    );
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: darwinPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      macOS: darwinPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      linux: linuxPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      taskNotificationId,
      'Background Service',
      'Service is running',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    taskNotificationId++;
  }

  Future<bool> _requestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations() async {
    if (await Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.isGranted) {
      return true;
    }
    final status = await Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations.request();
    return status.isGranted;
  }

  Future<bool> _requestPermissions() async {
    final status = await [
      Permission.location,
      Permission.notification,
      Permission.ignoreBatteryOptimizations,
    ].request();

    return status.values.every((permission) => permission.isGranted);
  }

  Future<void> cleanUp() async {
    await FlutterBackground.disableBackgroundExecution();
    await Workmanager().cancelAll();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }
}


if you set the ongoing parameter to true user will not be able to kill the notification by swiping, but I understand that clear all deletes the notification I am also working on that issue, also can you provide the code to understand more of your situation. btw I am also stuck in part where I have to update the fired notification and also notification should be there after killing the app.

Can you please provide the snippet for updating the same?

So, on my devices (Samsung A52s & Linux Fedora 40), with the ongoing parameter set to true the notification cannot be deleted by the clear all button, instead the notification can be deleted by swiping! I'm shure about that.
Anyway, I've edited the question with my code...
Thanks!

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications you can read in detail about package there.
